# how do you specifiy how many items are shown (height) in a listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, size

I have this and it shows all of the items in the listbox but there are alot of them

```
    <label for=”Application”>Application:</label>
    <%= Html.ListBox("SelectedCategories", Model.Applications)%>
```

is there a way to show just show 5 items and add a scrollbar (compared to increasing the height of the listbox)

Comment: Checkout [this blog post](http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/).

Comment: i appreciate this article and agree with a lot of the points of the author.  That being said, i think he breaks his own rules.  The idea that selecting a dropdown box would then add that items to a list is NOT intuitive at all.  Dropdowns are for selection / filtering etc, not for adding items to other lists imo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could set the "size" attribute on the select element to 5. Like this:

```
<%= Html.ListBox("SelectedCategories", Model.Applications, new {size=5})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use MVC5.2 +, try this:

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selected_categories,Model.categories,new { size = 5})